# Combine two vim commands into one

Tags: vim

I'm having trouble combining two vim commands, specifically `<C-w>s` and `<leader>x` into `<leader>r` (i.e. split window and open spec counterpart of current file). Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried writing a function for it? You can write a function like this (in ``.vimrc`` or ``.vim/ftplugin``): ``function SomeName() .. do stuff .. end function`` (with newlines) and map the function ``map <leader>r call SomeName``.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you'd post what exactly you've tried that didn't work. Generally, doing what you describe should be simple. It should be enough to put this in your `.vimrc` file:

```
nmap <leader>r <c-w>s<leader>x
```

This maps `<leader>r` to expand to the key sequence `<c-w>s<leader>x`. Note that these are not "commands", as you call them in your question, they're "mappings". A "command" is something completely different in vim, you can read up on that with `:help user-commands`.

One thing to be careful of is using `nmap` instead of `nnoremap`. The command `nmap` maps the sequence on the left to the sequence on the right while re-using mappings that have already been defined. On the other hand, `nnoremap` creates a mapping with the original meanings of the keys, so in your case won't work (since `<leader>x` is defined by some plugin). This is one possible reason you may have failed while trying to do it, but I can't tell from your question.